# Every error show Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ExecuteSolutionController not defined in laravel

Tags: laravel

I always get "Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ExecuteSolutionController not defined" error.

I have set environment to local and debug to true. Now i place undefined veriable in blade view.

instead of show undefined variable it always display the Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ExecuteSolutionController not defined page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be solved: https://github.com/facade/ignition/pull/265. See issue: https://github.com/facade/ignition/issues/227 .

Check which version of Ignition are you using.

Comment: I downgraded from ^1.4 to exactly 1.4 as described in the comment https://github.com/facade/ignition/issues/227#issuecomment-573391012 but I get another error with the same view: `Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ShareReportController not defined.`